# How to Add to ListView Dynamically Using Action Bar Button

Tags: android, listview

I want to dynamically add items to my `ListView` in Android. However, I want this to be done when the user presses an action bar button. From what I have found, to do this, one needs to extend `ListActivity` and `ActionBarActivity` which Android doesn't support. How do I do this otherwise. Here is my code for `MainActivity` (which right now only extends `ActionBarActivity`):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

     /** Items entered by the user is stored in this ArrayList variable */
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    /** Declaring an ArrayAdapter to set items to ListView */
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle presses on the action bar items
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_new:
                addListElement();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_settings:

                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }


    private void addListElement() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Comment: `adapter.add(...); adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`...

Comment: You don't need to `extends ListActivity` to have a `ListView` that is just a convenience. You will just need to create a `ListView` and call `setAdapter()` on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `activity_main.xml` add a listview.. then use like below...

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewId);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

remove `setListAdapter(adapter);`

```
private void addListElement(String value) {

    list.add(value);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
```

OR

```
private void addListElement(String value) {

adapter.add(value);

}
```